# Base $b$ and efficient integer factorisation

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

I was just looking at the RSA encryption Wikipedia page. RSA encryption essentially boils down to our inability to factorise huge semi-primes.

But then I had the idea of converting the number to base $b$. If a base $b$ number $n$ ends in $0$, then $b|n$.

Furthermore, one only has to analyse base $p$, $p \in \mathbb{P}$ (prime numbers).

Therefore, if there exists an efficient algorithm for converting numbers to base $p$, would efficient factorisation be possible?

My question boils down to:

> What makes trial division inefficient? Is it simply the nature of the algorithm? Why? Or is it the task of actually running through all possible divisors?

Thanks!

Comment: It is the task of actually running through all possible divisors indeed. The essence of RSA is large prime numbers, [here](https://rtybase.blogspot.com/2012/05/factoring-big-numbers-and-rsa.html) is a short article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a number $p$ divides a number $n$, it suffices to find the remainder when $n$ is divided by $p$. [This can be done very quickly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/fastest-way-to-calculate-the-remainder-modular). As such, it is not the testing whether $p|n$ that is the difficulty, it's actually iterating through all the primes $p<\sqrt{n}$ (if a number is not prime, its smallest prime factor is less than $\sqrt{n}$). For example, to factor a number around $10^{20}$ via trial division, you need to test divisibility by [$455052511$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primepi(10%5E10)) distinct primes.