# Determine the remainder, when $77^{200}$ is divided by $54$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Is there any fast way to get the remainders of the division of large numbers?

Like$-$

$$\frac{77^{200}}{54}$$

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/fastest-way-to-calculate-the-remainder-modular).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $77^{200}=(77^{18})^{11}77^2\equiv23^2\bmod54$

Answer (score 1):

As $77\equiv23\pmod{54}, 77^n\equiv23^n$

As  [Carmichael](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) Function $\lambda(54)=18$

and as $(77,54)=1$

and as  $200\equiv2\pmod{18}$

$$23^{200}\equiv23^2{\pmod{54}}\equiv-11\equiv-11+54$$

Comment: *Please* don't answer dupes of FAQs (unless there is something *novel* that can be said, which is highly unlikely for problems like this).

Comment: totient function $\phi(54)=18$ too